# backpropagation - bias nodes and error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I am implementing the stochastic gradient descent version of backpropagation from Tom Mitchell's [Machine Learning](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/mitchell/ftp/mlbook.html) book which has the steps for each training instance $\langle\vec{x},\vec{t}\rangle$:

1. Input instance $\vec{x}$ and compute output $o_u$ for every unit $u$.
2. For each output unit $k$, compute error $\delta_k = o_k(1-o_k)(t_k-o_k)$
3. For each hidden unit $h$, compute error $\delta_h = o_h(1-o_h)\sum_{k \in outputs}(w_{kh}\delta_k)$
4. Update each weight $w_{ji} = w_{ji} + \eta\delta_j x_{ji}$

I would like bias units at both the input and hidden layers. Are the bias units treated like any other units, and specifically, do the bias units have $\delta$ error values associated with them? If I am in Matlab and implementing with matrices, would I simply concatenate a bias to $\vec{x}$ and to the outputs vector for the hidden layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simplicity, bias units are subsumed into the equation by extending the input vector adding a component which is always 1. Concretely,

$$
x = (x_{1}, ..., x_{n},1)
$$
so that the activation for each unit can then be rewritten as,
$$
a_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{N} w_{ij}x_{j} + w_{i0} = \sum_{j=0}^{N} w_{ij}x_{j}
$$

You can see a detailed derivation of the backpropagation rule in the paper [neural networks and their applications](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/downloads/BISHOP%20-%20NNA%20-%20RSI94.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Bias units have no incoming weights, so you don't need gradient per bias unit computed (you can compute it, but it will not be used in any subsequent computations). Only gradient for outcoming bias weights is needed. This is true for any training algorithm, not just SGD.